# "угадай число" на python с записью 3 лучших результатов

Tags: python

нужно сделать игру "угадай число" с записью 3 лучших результатов по кол-ву попыток в файле. притом, если игрок со своим результатом входит в топ 3, он должен вписать своё имя, и оно должно отображаться в файле в виде:

```
Player1 - 1 попытка
Player2 - 2 попытки и т.д.
```

пока есть такой кусок кода

```
rand_num = random.choice(rand_num_list)
attempts = 0
import random
import pickle

rand_num_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rand_num = random.choice(rand_num_list)
attempts = 0

# эти строчки раскоментить чтобы создать файл
# file = open("highScores.txt", "wb")
# file.close()

answer = int(input("Угадай число: "))
if answer == rand_num:
    attempts += 1
    print("Угадал")
    print(f'Тебе понадобилось {attempts} попыток')

elif answer < rand_num:
    print("Число слишком маленькое")
    attempts += 1

elif answer > rand_num:
    print("Число слишком большое")
    attempts += 1
```

Comment: Учитесь декомпозировать задачи. Берёте задачу, разбиваете на отдельные шаги. Потом эти шаги ещё разбиваете на более мелкие шаги. И так пока не останутся конкретные атомарные действия, которые понятно, как делать. Что в данной задаче непонятно? Вы начните делать то, что понимаете, а то, что не понимаете - оставьте на потом. Когда сделаете понятное - подумайте над непонятным. Возможно, к тому моменту вы поймёте, как это делать. Опыт приходит, когда что-то делаете.

Comment: Записываейте attemps в файл через pickle, анализируйте структуру данных которую создаст pickle, выводите результаты этого анализа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте следующий код:

```
file = open("highScores.txt", 'w')
file.write(PlayerName+' - '+attempts+' '+po)
file.close()
```

Вот полный код:

```
import random
rand_num = random.randint(1, 5)
attempts = 0
while True:
    answer = int(input("Угадай число: "))
    if answer == rand_num:
        attempts += 1
        print("Угадал")
        print(f'Тебе понадобилось {attempts} попыток')
        PlayerName=input('Введи своё имя: ')
        file = open("highScores.txt", 'w')
        file.write(PlayerName+' - '+str(attempts)+' попыток\n')
        file.close()
        break
    elif answer < rand_num:
        print("Число слишком маленькое")
        attempts += 1

    elif answer > rand_num:
        print("Число слишком большое")
        attempts += 1
```